# Can continuous translation of Wigner crystal be described by charge neutral density excitations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, crystals, phonons, collective-excitations

In a two-dimensional electron gas (2DEG), under conditions where electron-electron interactions predominate over kinetic energy contributions, the ground state is a Wigner crystal. This crystalline state consists of electrons organized into a triangular lattice structure. The Hartree-Fock description of this state is represented by a Slater determinant composed of Bloch states where only the lowest energy band($0^{th}$ band) is completely occupied.

The operator that shifts the position of all N electrons in direct space by a vector $\vec{\delta}$ is a unitary operator
\begin{align}
U(\vec{\delta}) = \hat{T}(\vec{\delta})^{\otimes N}.
\end{align}
Where, $\hat{T}(\delta) = e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{\vec{p}}\cdot\vec{\delta}}$ is translation operator that shifts a single particle wave function by amount $\vec{\delta}$. A charge neutral density excitation of momentum $\vec{q}=0$ and $\omega=0$, which is translation of overall lattice (say by amount $\vec{\delta}$), can be written as $Q ^\dagger(\vec{\delta})|\Psi\rangle$, where
\begin{align}
Q^\dagger(\vec{\delta})= \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}^+}\sum_{\vec{k}\in BZ} \left(X_{nk}(\vec{\delta})c^\dagger_{nk}c_{0k}-  Y_{nk}(\vec{\delta})c^\dagger_{0k}c_{nk}\right)
\end{align}
and $|\Psi\rangle$ is Hartree-Fock ground state.
Then,
\begin{align}
    \langle\Psi|\,Q(\vec{\delta})\,\hat{\rho}(\vec{r})\,Q^\dagger(\vec{\delta})\,|\Psi\rangle = \langle\Psi|\,U^\dagger(\vec{\delta})\,\hat{\rho}(\vec{r})\,U(\vec{\delta})\,|\Psi\rangle.
\end{align}
Therefore, in such scenario the density excitation operator is simply the continuous translation operator
\begin{align}
     U(\vec{\delta})&=Q^{\dagger}(\vec{\delta})\\
    \hat{T}(\vec{\delta})^{\otimes N}    &=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}^+}\sum_{\vec{k}\in BZ} \left(X_{nk}(\vec{\delta})c^\dagger_{nk}c_{0k}-  Y_{nk}(\vec{\delta})c^\dagger_{0k}c_{nk}\right)
\end{align}
Questions: In the above equation, the LHS is an N-body operator while the RHS is a one-body operator. This seems fishy. How can these be equal? Which makes me wonder:

1. Can I show that particle-hole excitations can describe lattice translations in Wigner crystal?
2. Is the single particle-hole excitation basis complete to describe any density excitations to the Hartree-Fock ground state?